# calculations using BigNumber.js with cryptocurrency prices often return scientific notation values

Tags: javascript, node.js, bignumber.js

How can I deal with scientific notation values?

I do some calculations on crypto prices and most often of the time I get scientific notation values returned where I actually want normal values.

For example API response contains values like this

```
    {
    "symbol": "CERE",
    "current": 100309059.80168542,
    "previous": 100309059.80168541,
    "change": 1.3383748922e-8,
    "percentage": -6.671e-15
},
```

What do I have to do, in order to make this values as normal decimal numbers? I tried adding a "+" before, using "toPrecision()" but nothing changed.

Comment: they are already `Number`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `toFixed()` function from BigNumber

[image: BigNumber]

you can alternatively use the built-in function, `Number.toFixed()` but you should to pass in at least 18